# Allow Django model to load non specified DB fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have non managed model (having `managed = False`), which has specified only single field. However, DB table contains more fields than specified on model. I would like retrieve **ALL** fields, even those, which are not specified by Django's model.

**My Model:**

```py
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "employees"
        managed = False
```

**My Employees DB table:**

```
|-----------------------------------
| id | active  | address           |
|-----------------------------------
| 1  | true    | Dolphins street 5 |
|-----------------------------------
| 2  | false   | Green Avenue 1/C  |
|-----------------------------------
```

**What I want:**

```py
e = Employees.objects.first()
print(e.address)  # Will return "Dolphins street 5"
```

**The problem:**

```py
e = Employees.objects.first()
print(e.address)  # Will raise in Attribute error
```

I don't want to specify `Employee.address` field, because Django would force me to specify `max_length`. However, `max_length` is irrelevant for my application, because my model has `managed = False`. Moreover, DB definition of employees table is managed by third party software.